# Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. Alchemy does not hold users' private keys

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat, alchemy

I can't execute a send transaction method of my smart contract from the frontend by Alchemy

I am a beginner and I am trying to execute a method from my frontend that sends a transaction to the blockchain but I get an error from alchemy saying that the transaction needs to be signed with my private key but I have no idea how to do this and I did not find anything similar In Internet

[Error in the front: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transactionHash')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIs34.png)

[Error in Alchemy: Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. Alchemy does not hold users' private keys. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFXX.png)

[Error in Alchemy: {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"error": {
"code": -32600,
"message": "Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. Alchemy does not hold users' private keys. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis"
},
"id": 4
}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wteVq.png)

Comment: You have no account/signer imported. People might not know the alchemy "frontend" maybe you can specify your problem of importing a signer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKpUKmPTHjg&lc=UgxIii8MVxKe6XnAK694AaABAg&ab_channel=web3c%C3%A0fe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).