# When call write method :Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. Alchemy does not hold users' private keys

Tags: javascript, react-native, web3js, metamask, wallet-connect

My calling smart contract method is: Transfer ethers and use alchemy . when clicking the button call payDrink method then show this error:

> [Error: Returned error: Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction. Alchemy does not hold users' private keys. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis]

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';
const web3 = new Web3("https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/YPhlCYJ_fLdms1LpSRNs1n6rfcIqGHT9");
    const payDrink = (async () => {
    
    console.log("ethAmount");
    try{
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ContractAbi,contractAddress);
    const transaction = await contract.methods.transfer().send({
      from: '0x9126de09872d12c4f6d417e2cb6061d1ad9e4708',
      value: web3.utils.toWei("0.0001", 'ether'),
  });
    const transactionReciept = await transaction.wait();
    console.log(transactionReciept);}
    catch(err){console.log("eee",err);}
           
    })
```

[image: Check Screenshoot : alchemy error]

Comment: does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73171892/unsupported-method-eth-sendtransaction-alchemy-does-not-hold-users-private-ke)

Comment: no its not worked for me

Comment: what didn't work for you? And no, I haven't solved the issue, I searched for other people having the same issue and suggested the first result.

Answer (score 0):

there are many different methods for making web3 objects.
by using the network RPC URL you have to make HTTP provide first. Then it passes into the Web3 object.

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(Your Network RPC URL);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Now this should work perfectly.